# How do I offset Material-UI Popper (popper.js library) position on y-axis?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, popper.js

[image]

I am using a material-ui (v 4.9.5) `Popper` for a "pop-out" menu as above. It's `anchorElement` is the selected `ListItem` on the left. 
I want the `Popper` to appear flush with the top of the main menu. However it appears 5px short.

If I look at the Chrome Dev Tools I see the following and the `5px` value within the `translate3d` parameters is the issue. If I change the value to `0px` within the Dev Tools the problem is solved.

[image]

My question is how do I get this to happen through the code. I've tried the following using `modifiers` for the underlying **popper.js** and it *does nothing*.

```
 <Popper
    modifiers={{
        offset: {
         enabled: true,
         offset: '-5, 0'
    },
    }}
    className={globalMenuStyle.popperStyle}
    placement="right-end"
    open={isPopoverOpen}
    onClose={handleHidingGlobalMenu}
    anchorEl={anchorElement}>
    {popoverMenuItems}
 </Popper>
```

Even stranger is that if I experiment and try something like this and try the x-axis for the `modifiers` it shifts along the x-axis. **Why does x-axis work and y-axis doesn't ?**

```
modifiers={{
   offset: {
    enabled: true,
    offset: '0, 50'
},
}}
```

[image]

Comment: If you can share the code, or better try to reproduce this issue in a codesandbox, I'll try to help you

Answer (score 18):

Version 5.0 of Material UI and up uses Popper 2.0 which has slightly different syntax.

```
<Popper
    modifiers={[
      {
        name: "offset",
        options: {
          offset: [0, 50],
        },
      },
    ]}
  >
  </Popper>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the [**`popperOptions`**](https://material-ui.com/api/popper/#popper-api) prop to provide the options obj to the popper.js instance like so:

```
<Popper
   popperOptions={{
      modifiers: {
         offset: {
             offset: '-5,0',
         },
      },
    }}
    ....
</Popper>
```

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Try update material-ui maybe? I'm on 4.9.9 and both x and y offsets are working for me.

Comment: try modifiers: {
         offset: {
             enabled: true,
             offset: '-5,0',
         },
      }

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest way to add offset to the Material Ui popper component.

```
  <Popper
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
        modifiers={{
          flip: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          offset: {
            enabled: true,
            offset: '300,100',
          },
        
      >
```

the reference here for more info
[MUI](https://material-ui.com/api/popper/)
[popper.js](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/#offset)