# How can I offset a MUI Popover component from an anchorEl?

Tags: material-ui, popover

With `anchorOrigin`, I can give a [MUI Popover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/) an offset with `anchorPosition.top` and `anchorPosition.left`. But this has no effect when I'm using an `anchorEl` (i.e., attaching the popover to a trigger element), not an `anchorOrigin` (i.e., using absolute positioning).

It seems I can do this with the [MUI Popper](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popper/)
(see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975186/how-do-i-offset-material-ui-popper-popper-js-library-position-on-y-axis)), but not very easily with the popover. I want the clickaway functionality so apart from this positioning difficulty I prefer the popover.

What's the best way to attach to an element but shift the popover (say, down and right)?

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass a number to the `horizontal` and `vertical` properties to have them offset with respect to the top-left corner of the anchor element, like this:

```
<Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 100,
        }}
      >
        <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
```

this will open the popover 100 pixels to the right of the left margin of the `anchorEl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Popover [transformOrigin](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popover/#Popover-prop-transformOrigin) property to shift popover in right-bottom direction.

Example:

```js
<Popover
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  open={open}
  onClose={closePopover}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: 'bottom',
    horizontal: 'left',
  }}
  transformOrigin={{vertical: -20, horizontal: -20}}
>...content</Popover>
```